# Summing Time from time differences between time that's split in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Once again I need your help guys. 
I have a table that looks like this:

```
Hour_start | Minute_start | Second_start | Hour_end | Minute_end | Second_end
10         | 10           | 00           | 10       | 15         | 30
11         | 12           | 00           | 11       | 14         | 47
```

So I would like the output to sum differences between the start and end times.
Output in this case would look like this and it should be only in minutes:

```
8:17 */(because 5:30 + 2:47)/*
```

I use T-SQL (MS SQL Server) from external app that won't let me use something like @declare and so on. I can only use standard queries like select, create, drop etc.

Comment: Start with adding the components together to time values. Then do the calculation.

Comment: You can't add `time` datatypes together in SQL Server. You can, however, work out the number of minutes/seconds between 2 dates/times (`DATEDIFF`) and then convert that to a `time` (`DATEADD`, provided it's under `24:00:00`). Have you tried anything yourself so far? If not, please do so and share your attempt.

Comment: You are requesting that the result should only be in minutes. Your example is also showing seconds as expected result

Answer (score 2):

Step 1) Fire whoever designed [this table](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Step 2) This seems to do it<sup>1</sup>:

```
declare @t table (Hour_start int, Minute_start int, Second_start int,
                  Hour_end int, Minute_end int, Second_end int)
insert into @t(Hour_start , Minute_start , Second_start ,
               Hour_end , Minute_end , Second_end) values
(10         , 10           , 00           , 10       , 15         , 30),
(11         , 12           , 00           , 11       , 14         , 47)

;With Total as (
    select
        SUM(
        DATEDIFF(second,
        DATEADD(hour,hour_start,
        DATEADD(minute,minute_start,
        DATEADD(second,second_start,
        CONVERT(time,'00:00:00')))),
        DATEADD(hour,hour_end,
        DATEADD(minute,minute_end,
        DATEADD(second,second_end,
        CONVERT(time,'00:00:00')))))
        ) as Seconds
    from
        @t
)
select
    CONVERT(varchar(10),Seconds/60) + ':' +
    RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(10),Seconds%60),2)
from Total
```

You might be tempted to cast the result to `time` (the type that should have been used in the table in the first place). Don't do this. `time` represents a *time of day*. The result is a *time span*. These are two distinct (though obviously related) concepts.

There may be quicker ways to bootstrap the conversion of these columns into `time`, but I prefer the explicit `CONVERT` that makes it clearer what we're doing.

---

<sup>1</sup>Yes, there's a `declare` in this script, and you've said that's not allowed, but that's just there to make the script self-contained and runnable. The `declare` and `insert` are just setting up your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If MS SQL SERVER version is 2012 or newer you can use `TIMEFROMPARTS` to find TIME, and you can use `DATEDIFF` to find difference.

```
CREATE TABLE #Times
(
    Hour_start INT
    ,Minute_start INT
    ,Second_start INT
    ,Hour_end INT
    ,Minute_end INT
    ,Second_end INT
)

INSERT INTO #Times VALUES
(10,10,00,10,15,30)
,(11,12,00,11,14,47)

SELECT   TIMEFROMPARTS(Hour_start,Minute_start,Second_start,0,0) StartTime
        ,TIMEFROMPARTS(Hour_end,Minute_end,Second_end,0,0) EndTime
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TIMEFROMPARTS(Hour_start,Minute_start,Second_start,0,0),TIMEFROMPARTS(Hour_end,Minute_end,Second_end,0,0)) TimeDifference
FROM #Times
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do time mathematics in seconds without any SQL built in date time function and assuming that both times are from same day.

```
    select 
      concat(
         CAST(diffinSeconds/60 as Nvarchar(max)),
        ':',
         CAST(diffinseconds%60 as nvarchar(max)))
    from 
     (
       select diffinSeconds=
        SUM(
              (Hour_end  - Hour_start) *3600 + 
              (Minute_end-Minute_start) *60 + 
              (Second_end-Second_start)
            ) 
       from yourtable
   )t
```

Answer (score 0):

My Query found Hour also.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Startstop](
[Hour_start] [int] NULL,
[Minute_start] [int] NULL,
[Second_start] [int] NULL,
[Hour_end] [int] NULL,
[Minute_end] [int] NULL,
[Second_end] [int] NULL
) 

insert Startstop(Hour_start , Minute_start , Second_start ,
           Hour_end , Minute_end , Second_end) values
(10         , 10           , 00           , 10       , 15         , 30),
(11         , 12           , 00           , 11       , 14         , 47)

declare @TempTable Table (TotalSecond int,Hour int)
insert @TempTable
select sum((((Hour_end *3600)+(Minute_end * 60)+Second_end)  - ((Hour_start *3600)+ 
(Minute_start * 60)+Second_Start))) 
,sum((((Hour_end *3600)+(Minute_end * 60)+Second_end)  - ((Hour_start *3600)+ 
(Minute_start * 60)+Second_Start))/3600) Hour
from Startstop


select Hour, (TotalSecond-(Hour* 3600)) /60 Minute , TotalSecond - (Hour *3600) - 
((((TotalSecond-(Hour* 3600)) /60))*60) Second
from @TempTable
```

I 'm using 2008